# JavaFX: Border not rendered correctly for button

Tags: java, button, javafx, javafx-8, border

Recently I noticed that the buttons in my application are not rendering correctly.

[image]

In this example, the button has gray border. The problem is that the background of the button is bigger than the bounds of the border.

How do I make the border appear just outside the bounds of the background?

Comment: Are you using custom CSS on this? If so, can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I looked through my whole project and changed the CSS all over the places... Then I realized something - that extra space that looks like the button's background fill, is not actually that.

I added this to my stylesheet:

```
.root
{
    -fx-shadow-highlight-color: red;
}
```

And surprisingly, this is how it looks like now:

[image]

So it's actually a shadow for the button. Most of the time it's not obvious because this is how Modena.css defines it:

```
-fx-shadow-highlight-color: ladder(
    -fx-background,
    rgba(255,255,255,0.07) 0%,
    rgba(255,255,255,0.07) 20%,
    rgba(255,255,255,0.07) 70%,
    rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 90%,
    rgba(255,255,255,0.75) 100%
);
```

So if a custom background color is specified on any of the button's ancestor nodes, then this shadow would visually look odd.

Comment: Hmm, I tried on a brand new project and it didn't have this problem....